# MKAnnotationView setImage() on iOS 11 has an animation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Since iOS 11, when I use `setImage` in my custom `MKAnnotationView`, the image is displayed with an animation.

The problem is when I select and deselect the `MKAnnotationView` and the image has a different size. It results in a weird animation.

No problem until iOS 11, can we stop this behaviour?

Comment: I've tried `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{}]` but not works. This weird animation is really annoying.

Answer (score 10):

Seeing that this is the only mention of this issue (feature?) that I've found *anywhere* over the past year and a half, let me first thank you for being my only source of sanity. With that, I've finally been able to circle back and demystify this...sort of. I've yet to file a radar, only because it is unclear whether this behavior is intended. Whatever the correct behavior, the animation has some odd side-effects, and led me to [report a separate issue](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5001608584757248).

## The Problem

To boil it down, the `image` field is **not an animatable field**, but updating it outside of a user-defined transaction triggers a system-performed path animation from the previous image to the new image. Since the animations are performed at the layer-level, `UIKit` will not be able to stop them. Instead, we have to halt the current thread transaction's animation actions entirely so that the nested layer animations are never allowed to perform:

```swift
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
annotationView.image = newImage
CATransaction.commit()
```

#### Modifying Existing Animation

Rather than cutting off the animation completely, you can also de-jank the path animation by injecting your own properties to the current thread transaction. The catch here, though, is that in order to correctly animate the path & make the appearance that the image isn't moving (ex. animating from a small pin to a large pin), we have to synchronize an additional animation of the `centerOffset`. This field does `not` directly modify the layer, but it does appear to be a UIKit-animatable field. This means that you need to combine a UIKit animation with a CoreAnimation transaction:

```swift
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn))

UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.image = newImage
    self.centerOffset = newCenterOffset
}, completion: nil)

CATransaction.commit()
```

The duration & timing function must be the same for both the UIKit animation & the CoreAnimation transaction.

Comment: It looks like disabling the `annotationView.image` animation with `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)` no longer works on iOS 15

Comment: @AleksanderMaj I'm seeing the same thing. `CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.0)` seems to have a similar effect though.