# MKAnnotationView image toggling's transition issue

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have 2 image states for the MKAnnotationView, which are `selected` and `deselected`. The issue is that the transition between these two states is poor. There isn't much online about this and I'm having trouble with transitions, generally.

[image]

Here is the `MKAnnotationView` I am using:

```
class CustomPinView: MKAnnotationView {
    func updateImage() {
        guard let mapAnnotation = annotation as? MapAnnotation else {return}
        if let selectedImageName = mapAnnotation.selectedImageName, isSelected {
            image = UIImage(inCurrentBundleWithName: selectedImageName)
        } else if let imageName = mapAnnotation.imageName {
            image = UIImage(inCurrentBundleWithName: imageName)
        } else {
            image = nil
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        updateImage()
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the `updateImage` function to look like this:

```
private func updateImage() {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            guard let mapAnnotation = self.annotation as? MapAnnotation else {return}
            if let selectedImageName = mapAnnotation.selectedImageName, self.isSelected {
                self.image = UIImage(inCurrentBundleWithName: selectedImageName)
                self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.6)
            } else if let imageName = mapAnnotation.imageName {
                self.image = UIImage(inCurrentBundleWithName: imageName)
                self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            } else {
                self.image = nil
            }
            self.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        }, completion: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

This is extracted from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431257/4114335